# Eclipse: Create placeholder function from unrecognized function name?

Tags: eclipse, fdt

Perhaps I'm using the wrong search terms, or maybe eclipse just doesn't support this, but when I type a function call to a function that I haven't written yet, is there a way to have eclipse automatically create an empty placeholder function with the same name?

I'm using FDT to do ActionScript3 coding, if that makes any difference.

For example, if I type this:

```
var x = func(5.2);
```

but I haven't written the `func` function yet, eclipse will underline `func` to alert me that it can find a reference to that function. This is presenting me with a problem, but not a solution. Is there a keyboard shortcut to have eclipse automatically go to this:

```
var x = func(5.2);

private function func():void {
    // add your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Ctrl-1 (Windows) or Cmd-1 (MacOS).